# Can not set font-weight

Tags: html, css

I have two fonts:

```
font: normal 12px/18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font: normal 15px/20px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
```

I need to set font-weight for these fonts with values 400 and 600. Values <=500 makes font normal, >=600 makes font bold. What should I do to get font-weight different from normal or bold?

Comment: You can only do that with fonts that actually have more than two weights. Most do have only the two.

Answer (score 1):

Some fonts have more than two weights. Values could range from 100-900. Read about it [HERE](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#font-weight-prop).

- 100 - Thin
- 200 - Extra Light (Ultra Light)
- 300 - Light
- 400 - Normal
- 500 - Medium
- 600 - Semi Bold (Demi Bold)
- 700 - Bold
- 800 - Extra Bold (Ultra Bold)
- 900 - Black (Heavy)

Comment: Can my fonts have  more than two weights?

Comment: @MyName That depends on which ones. Like I said, some do, most don't. For instance, the Google font Barlow has all 9. See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/zrjaLm1b/).

Comment: @MyName depends on the font as said. some have 2, some have 3, etc.